# Cannot figure out the correct way to use abstract methods

Tags: java, abstract

My assignment is as follows:

Write a Java interface named Searchable with two abstract methods: one named Way2Search that returns a String and another named MaxTime that returns an Integer. Be sure your code compiles and runs as expected. Name your Java file Searchable.java.

This seems easy enough. However, I have been hung up for days on this and it is due tomorrow.

Code is as follows:

```
public interface Searchable {
        public String Way2Search();
        public Integer MaxTime();
}
```

Is it really as simple as this code. Is this all it is asking me to do?

Comment: That's how I'd interpret it. (Although the assignment is going against Java's naming conventions.)

Comment: LGTM as far as the explanation goes.

Comment: If that's the entire question,  them it looks like that's all you are asked to do

Comment: Ok thanks, I just wanted somebody else's opinion, I was thinking to deep into it. I guess I will find out tomorrow. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you got it. An interface is just unimplemented method signatures. You would then implement those methods in the classes that `implements` your `Searchable` interface. The benefit of this is that you could implement (i.e. fill out the method body) of those methods differently in the various classes that `implements` your interface.

e.g.

```
class A implements Searchable {
    ...         
    public String way2Search() {
         //implement this method in one way here
    }
    public Integer maxTime() {
         //implement this method in one way here
    }
}
```

/

```
class B implements Searchable {
    ...     
    public String way2Search() {
         //implement this method in a different way here
    }
    public Integer maxTime() {
         //implement this method in a different way here
    }
}
```